# Redirect user using htaccess in my Laravel application

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I am having trouble with my configuration of htaccess in my laravel application.

I am using the following codes to redirect user to the right path. I tried to add host_name to my htaccess but it breaks the inner pages of the application.
IP address redirection is working fine now.

`File : laravel_app/public/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10\.10\.10\.201$
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host_name$          -- It breaks the other page.
    RewriteRule (.*) http://host_name.maindomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

User can manually navigate to the ff:

```
http://host_name/login
http://10.10.13.201/login
```

But i want them to use the rigth path below :

```
http://host_name.maindomain.com/login
```

Is this achievable using htaccess?

Edit : 
`http://host_name.maindomain.com` is pointed to `laravel_app/public`.

Comment: Is `host_name.maindomain.com` domain pointing to your `laravel_app` directory or `laravel_app/public`?

Comment: @RossWilson It is pointed to laravel_app/public.

Answer (score 1):

You can not chain the `RewriteCond`, so your `.htaccess` has an invalid configuration since it will only try to bind the last condition and the first one has no corresponding rule:

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10\.10\.13\.201$
RewriteRule (.*) http://host_name.maindomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^host_name$      
RewriteRule (.*) http://host_name.maindomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[See the demo](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=f2eef669-d874-5426-b309-85cf1e69882e)

Comment: when i tried to append that syntax together with the default .htaccess of laravel. It gives me a wrong behaviour . https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=49797177-22f6-54eb-ae4f-a636b1ed7ad3

Comment: You should put the domain rewrite before the laravel rules

Comment: Tried to adjust it. Weird behavior still occurs on right path - https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=f855f03a-ae8a-5e09-af81-ae1df2739723

Comment: What do you mean with `weird behavior`? Because what I see here is what I would expect to happen

Comment: Using my previous link, when i try to navigate to `http://host_name.maindomain.com/file-manager?test=1` it redirects me to `http://host_name.maindomain.com/index.php?test=1` where segment `file-manager` is missing.

Comment: That is the expected behavior for a laravel application, every request needs to go through index.php since that bootstraps your application. Laravel will alter your url accordingly later